# Android Studio: Opening file not searching through app

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio. I use `cmd+shift+O` to open files. Recently, Android Studio has stopped has stopped searching through my app files, and only displays the generated files.

I can't find anything to update the settings in the preference. Anyone know why this is?

For example, if I search for `NavigationActivity.java`, here's what I see:

[image]

Note that only generated files appear.

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+shift+a 
type file 
[image]

select File... 
you will see this 
[image]

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: checked that - all boxes are checked

Comment: that's weird. did you try restarting Android Studio? and how about shift shift (search everywhere)?

Comment: I tried restarting Android Studio...and eventually my computer. Neither worked. I just checked shift+shift, and that worked - didn't know about that command. I'll have to switch to that for now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it works. Use shift shift as a workaround for now.